# sql - get consecutive presents and absences

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing an attendance monitoring database application for a church which the objective is to get the consecutive presents and absences for each member. but the consecutive counts would be based by week

for example we have 3 services a week (one on Monday, one on Wednesday and one on Friday), but those services are the same, (only difference is the time/date) . so a member can attend ANY of those meetings (they can attend all if they want)

I have to find the consecutive presents and absences for each member based on week, for example 
if my attendance in the month od December 2014 is:

```
     S   M   T   W   T   F   S
W1   -   P   -   P   -   -   -
W2   -   P   -   -   -   -   -
W3   -   P   -   P   -   P   -
W4   -   -   -   -   -   P   -
W5   -   P   -   -   -   -   -
```

I have 5 CONSECUTIVE PRESENTS
I must only count one attendance per week (any other presences will be ignored)

here is the table

tbl_members

```
member_id  last_name  first_name ... and so on
1          SANTIAGO   JOHN KERNELLE
```

tbl_service_attendances

```
att_index  service_date  member_id
1          2014-12-01    1
2          2014-12-03    1
3          2014-12-08    1
4          2014-12-15    1
5          2014-12-17    1
6          2014-12-19    1
7          2014-12-26    1
8          2014-12-29    1
```

att_index is auto increment

for every attend of a member, I use this query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_service_attendances(service_date, member_id) VALUES('2014-12-29', 1)
```

If they attended 8 services in a week, the tbl_service_attendances will have 8 rows for each of it (the only difference would be their dates). But it will only count as 5 CONSECUTIVE PRESENTS. (one count per week)

```
    S   M   T   W   T   F   S
W1  -   P   -   P   -   -   -
W2  -   P   -   -   -   -   -
W3  -   P   -   P   -   P   -
W4  -   -   -   -   -   -   -
W5  -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

In this case, I have 2 CONSECUTIVE ABSENTS,

I have to also know if the Consecutives are presences or absences

please help, thanks in advance

so far i have done my objective by looping a query, but I think that looping multiple queries is not advisable

Comment: Which RDBMS please (Sql Server, MySql, Oracle, etc)

Comment: Why do you care who shows up?

Comment: @Strawberry, In our church, If a member is absent for 2 or more consecutive weeks, they will be included in the list that needs a visitation, some members close to them will visit them to know if they have problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this kind of problem is much easier to deal with in DBMS that support window functions, but here is one idea that can be used with MySQL. Let's create a view first just to simplify matters:

```
create view wa as select distinct member_id, week(service_date) as wk 
                  from service_attendances;
```

I assume here that we are dealing with one year's worth of data. If not year has to included in the view and in the queries below.

With that view at hand we can create intervals of weekly attendances as:

```
select member_id, min(start_wk), end_wk 
from (
    select wa1.member_id, wa1.wk as start_wk, min(wa2.wk) as end_wk 
    from wa as wa1 
    join wa as wa2 
        on wa1.member_id = wa2.member_id 
       and wa2.wk > wa1.wk 
       and not exists ( 
           select 1 
           from wa wa3 
           where wa2.member_id = wa3.member_id 
             and wa3.wk = wa2.wk + 1
       ) 
    group by wa1.wk, wa1.member_id
) as x 
group by member_id, end_wk;
```

With the data you provided above the result is:

```
+-----------+---------------+--------+
| member_id | min(start_wk) | end_wk |
+-----------+---------------+--------+
|         1 |            48 |     52 |
+-----------+---------------+--------+
```

The gaps can be easily derived from this. It would have been easiest to create another view for this expression, but MySQL consider this cheating:

```
ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

Assume start_wk is 1 and end_wk is 52 for the year and you can use a similar technique as above to find the gaps for each member.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're welcome. If you believe the answer was useful you can vote for it and/or accept it as an answer. The same goes for Korianders solution.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use session variables, like in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0647e/6):

```
select IF (weekn = @prev + @n, 
           IF (@n := @n + 1, @prev, 1),
           IF (@n:=0 OR @prev := weekn, weekn, 2)) start_sequence
from (select distinct week(service_date) as weekn
  from   tbl_service_attendances
  where  member_id = 1
    and  year(service_date) = 2014
    and  month(service_date) = 12
  order by weekn) as presences
JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @prev := week('2014-12-01')-2) AS setup;
```

Consecutive weeks are replaced by the first week number of the sequence. From here, you can "group by" on this query, by start_sequence, "count" number of occurrences of the week, and discard those that occur only once.

It does not return yet the absences, but this can be done by

a) right joining with a lookup table with all week numbers you want

b) use negative week numbers to indicate those weeks of absence